# Select from mysql where id is different from $id

Tags: php, mysql

I have in php few diferent `$id variable.`

For example `$id=3`, and after that `$id=4`, and after `$id=5`...`

What I want is to

```
SELECT from mysql database WHERE id !=$id
```

I want select id who is different from 3 or 4 or 5

Comment: Are you trying to get all rows that doesn't equal that `$id`?

Comment: not in comment edit your questtion

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * from your_table 
WHERE id not in (3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all rows that are not equal to that `$id`?

If so, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id !=$id
```

EDIT:

But if your `$id` is an array with multiple ID's, you will need to do it like this:

```
$id_list=implode("','",$id);

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN ('$id_list')";
```

Comment: Yes but  I have few of $id value. if I put SELECT * FROM table WHERE id !=$id, it wil select id wich is different from the only last one $id.

Answer (score -1):

Try the NOT IN

The NOT operator is used to negate the result of an expression and is of particular use when using the IN operator. For example,lists all the products in our table that do NOT id 3, 4 or 5 simply by used a NOT IN operator combination:

```
SELECT * from MySQL_database_table WHERE id NOT IN (3,4,5)
```

Comment: Yes but I don't know how what is the value of $id before. 3,4,5 is the example

Comment: you can store the value of id any where like session or cookies or database

Answer (score -1):

If `$id` is array then you can use easily following method.

```
$id=array(2,3,4,9);
$id_list=implode("','",$id);

$sql="SELECT from mysql database WHERE id NOT IN ('$id_list')";  //for better way..
```

Comment: $id is id from past articles...So if I have 5 articles with different id I want that 6 article has different id from 5 before.

Comment: You can store before id in session by using `@session_start(); $_SESSION['id'][]=$before_id;`  and get before ids array by `$id=$_SESSION['id'];  //as array`

Answer (score -1):

Use quotes and Specify what to `SELECT`,

If you have to take all columns, use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE id <> '".$id."'";
```

OR specify column name(s),

```
SELECT column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, ... 
FROM tableName
WHERE id <> '".$id."'";
```